# How do I make a link update itself when its clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have next link that lets users navigate through a list of URL (stored in array). When a user clicks next, I want the link href and anchor to be updated for the next website in my array. The way I've tried so far, it link skips one URL each time, and I have and idea why, it has to do with the previous click even not completing, but what's the right way to do this?

Here is an example so you can see exactly what I'm talking about: http://jsbin.com/atobep

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){

    var items = [];
    $.each(urls, function(i, item) {
        items.push("<li>"+item['name']+"</li>");
    });

    $('#list').append(items.join(''));

    changeNextLink(0);
    $("#frame").attr('src', urls[0]['url']);

});

var urls = [{"name":"ebay","url":"http://ebay.com"},{"name":"amazon","url":"http://amazon.com"},{"name":"msn","url":"http://msn.com"},{"name":"yahoo","url":"http://yahoo.com"},{"name":"wikipedia","url":"http://wikipedia.org"}];

function changeNextLink(x){     

    $('#now').html(urls[x]['name']); //show the name of currently loaded page
    $('#nextLink').html(urls[x+1]['name']); //name of next website as anchor of next link
    $('#nextLink').attr('href', urls[x+1]['url']); //url to next website
    $('#nextLink').attr('onclick','changeNextLink('+(x+1)+')'); //the problem spot. prepare next link for next click.

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <ol id="list"></ol>

    now: <span id="now"></span> | next: <a href="" target="frame" id="nextLink"></a><br />
    <iframe name="frame" src="" id="frame" style="width:500px; height:600px;"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a new var to keep track of the next link num, and adding a click handler for `#nextLine`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var nextLinkNum = 0;
    var items = [];
    $.each(urls, function(i, item) {
        items.push("<li>"+item['name']+"</li>");
    });

    $('#list').append(items.join(''));

    changeNextLink(nextLinkNum);
    $("#frame").attr('src', urls[0]['url']);

    $('#nextLink').click(function() { 
        if (nextLinkNum + 1 < urls.length)
            changeNextLink(++nextLinkNum); 
    });

});

function changeNextLink(x){     
    $('#now').html(urls[x]['name']); //show the name of currently loaded page
    $('#nextLink').html(urls[x+1]['name']); //name of next website as anchor of next link
    $('#nextLink').attr('href', urls[x+1]['url']); //url to next website
    $('#nextLink').attr('onclick','changeNextLink('+(x+1)+')'); //the problem spot. prepare next link for next click.
}
```

Comment: @AdamRackis I like the elegance of this solution. Most likely I will go with this. Thank you.

Comment: @AdamRackis
I ran into a problem while implementing this. Let me update the jsBin and post it.

Comment: @ofko - I'm really not sure.  It's hard to follow things like this in comment threads.  You might want to gather this all up and post it as a new question.  I think that would get you the best results.

Comment: Disregarding my previous comments, could you please complete your answer by adding the changeNextLink function to your code? The current function is not working as properly when used with your code.

Comment: You can see the result with that here: http://jsbin.com/atobep/7
(not working right)
I would post a new question but it will probably get flagged for duplication.

Comment: This also confuses me because, if $.click is being used, why is 'onclick' attribute needed?

Comment: Gather up your new code, explain the problem, and ask a new Q clearly.  It won't get flagged.

Comment: @ofko - it's not --  $().click(function... replaces onclick

Answer (score 0):

I made some slight changes to your javascript and it seems to be working correctly now...

http://jsbin.com/atobep/5/edit

First it will check if there's another url next in the list, if not the next url will be set to the current url (You can set it back to the first one if you want). If there is another one in the list, then set it to be the next url.

Comment: Part of the point of Q&A here on SO is to share with the public what changes you made and why rather than just pasting in a link to code.